# Referencing textbox in subreport from main report

Tags: ms-access

I have a main report that I would like to have a textbox on that references the subreport.  I used the format [Subreport].[Report]![Textbox] which did pull the textbox over.  The problem I have is the textbox on the subreport contains a sum total (e.g. =SUM([SumOfTotalHours]).  When the information appears on the main report, it does not display the total of hours; however, it shows only the first record in the textbox.  For example, if the subreport had 3 records that were 1,2,3 and my sum total text box correctly shows 6, on the main report it would show 1.  I'm not sure what I am missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try having a textbox, *TxtSum*, on the subreport with this ControlSource:

```
=Sum([SumOfTotalHours])
```

Then reference that on the main report:

```
=[Subreport].[Report]![TxtSum]
```

Comment: That's what I currently have setup and it gives me only the value of the first record, not the sum total.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a text box on your main report that displays the total from the subreport:

```
  Name:  txtTotLabsRunSum  
  Control Source: =srptCtrlName.Report.txtTotalControlOnSub  
  Running Sum: Over All
```

Then add a text box to your main report's footer:

```
  Control Source: =txtTotLabsRunSum
```

Duane MS Access MVP